# Problems with enlarging images on hover with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dreamweaver

The bunch of code does seem to work, only thing is that the transition is not very smooth. Any Idea how to tweak up the code to make the effect more smooth? and also, when the image enlarges, all the content below and beside the image seems to be pushed away to make room for the enlargement, any idea how I can stop this and just make the image overlap the content around it on enlargement? Also, instead of inserting that code for each image every time I upload a new image and want that effect, how do I make the javascript code automatically apply to the new image instead of manually applying the javascript to it each time? Finally, how do I use this on videos/widgets instead of just images? (I’m using Dreamweaver CS5).

```
$("img").each(function() {
$.data(this, 'size', { width: $(this).width(), height: $(this).height() });
}).hover(function() {
$(this).stop().animate({ height: $.data(this,'size').height*1.2,
width: $.data(this,'size').width*1.2 });
}, function() {
$(this).stop().animate({ height: $.data(this,'size').height,
width: $.data(this,'size').width });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to overlap any surrounding elements upon resize you will have to play with the CSS to position the element either relative, absolute, or fixed, then set the z-index of the image to a value higher than the surrounding elements.

Comment: I habe been tweaking the CSS for that, nothing seems to be working dude.

Comment: The surrounding elements still seem to be displaced on enlargment

Comment: can you provide the css? if an element is "position"ed correctly it should not affect the surrounding elements.

Comment: The CSS is useless, I've tried everything I know of, different positioning, tweaking the z-index! Nothing seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds maybe like you should look into a jQuery Lightbox plugin. As for the specific issue with the enlarged image pushing your content around, it needs to be removed from the document flow (using position attribute)... but that's just the tip of an iceberg. There's a lot of moving parts to the task you're trying to achieve, that's why using an existing javascript plugin would be best - IMO, of course.

You might want to check out http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/ and also http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts .